# Brake judder on new rotors

Tags: toyota, brakes, corolla

2013 Corolla have replaced front pads, rotors, pistons, bled fluid, still rotors overheating causing 'judder' when braking?

Comment: When you say 'judder' do you mean a pulsing in your stearing wheel when you apply the brakes?

Comment: How did you go about bedding the brakes?

Comment: Did you check the runout when you installed the rotors? Do they judder under hard braking, or just when you initially touch the brakes and then goes away when you press harder?

Comment: Were the rotors torqued properly?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you replace the caliper pistons on a 2013MY vehicle?
In any case, from my experience brake judder usually comes from different brand rotors and pads which may or may not subside as time goes on and the two wear together. Other than that its cheap rotors with too much of a wave cast/ground into the face.
I also just noticed you say your rotors are overheating, are you racing your Corolla? If not I cant see why your rotors would overheat, unless you drive and brake very aggressively everyday.

Comment: Just a thought: Overheating could also come from incorrect pads or rotors (too wide for the caliper), seized piston, or misaligned caliper, but those are pretty rare when replacing with stock parts.

Comment: This is true, although I have yet to experience this sort of overheating. Poor parts quality and or labor quality could definitely be a cause to the things you listed.

Comment: I have *never* used the same brand for pads and rotors and have *never* had this problem. Where did that idea come from?